# Not able to open task scheduler using pywinauto

Tags: scheduled-tasks, pywinauto

I am trying to start Task Scheduler using pywinauto, but getting error

> pywinauto.application.AppStartError: Could not create the process "C:\Windows\System32    askschd.msc

Below code written in python:

```
from pywinauto.application import Application
app = Application(backend='uia').start('C:\Windows\System32\taskschd.msc')
```

If I am trying to connect with task scheduler if task scheduler is already open, then getting below error

> getting pywinauto.findwindows.ElementNotFoundError: {'title': 'Task Scheduler', 'backend': 'uia', 'visible_only': False}

Below code given to connect task scheduler if already open:

```
from pywinauto.application import Application
app = Application(backend='uia').connect(title='Task Scheduler')
```

Is there something I'm doing wrong?

Comment: I would recommend learning `schtasks /?`. GUI automation is overkill for such things!

Comment: Regarding connect issue you need `timeout=10` explicitly for now (known issue with default timeout).